# How to get system root directory for Windows in Google Golang?

Tags: windows, go

Under Windows, the system root directory could be like `C://` or `D://` (when the OS is installed in driver `D:/`). How to get this folder in Go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `filepath.VolumeName(os.GetEnv("SYSTEMROOT")) + "\\"` or the shorter `os.GetEnv("SYSTEMDRIVE") + "\\"`. The `windir` environment variable probably shouldn't be used anymore honestly since it is not a system-controlled environment variable.

[Source for the mentioned environment variables](https://superuser.com/a/638335/135137)

Answer (score 1):

You may use os.Getenv to get the value for "environment" variable windir. An example is below:

```
package main
import "os"
import "fmt"


func main() {

    fmt.Println("system dir: ", os.Getenv("windir"))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options that work with Windows or Unix.

```
import "os"

func root() string {
   return os.Getenv("SystemDrive") + string(os.PathSeparator)
}
```

```
import (
   "os"
   "path/filepath"
)

func root() string {
   s := os.TempDir()
   return filepath.Join(s, "..", "..")
}
```

```
import (
   "os"
   "strings"
)

func root() string {
   s := os.TempDir()
   return s[:strings.IndexRune(s, os.PathSeparator) + 1]
}
```

```
import (
   "os"
   "path/filepath"
)

func root() string {
   s := os.TempDir()
   return filepath.VolumeName(s) + string(os.PathSeparator)
}
```

```
import (
   "os"
   "strings"
)

func root() string {
   s := os.TempDir()
   return strings.SplitAfterN(s, string(os.PathSeparator), 2)[0]
}
```

- https://golang.org/pkg/os#Getenv
- https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath#Join
- https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath#VolumeName
- https://golang.org/pkg/strings#IndexRune
- https://golang.org/pkg/strings#SplitAfterN