# How to get root of filesystem in Go in an OS-agnostic way

Tags: windows, go, unix, filesystems, os-agnostic

I want to get the root directory of the filesystem in Go in such a way that it will work on both Windows and Unix.

I thought I could do something like

```
func fsRootDir() string {
    s := os.Getenv("SystemDrive")
    if s != "" {
        return s
    }
    return "/"
}
```

However, there are a couple problems with this, so I rejected this approach:

- A user could create a `SystemDrive` environment variable on Unix with some bogus path.
- A user could change the value of the `SystemDrive` environment variable on Windows to some bogus path.

I looked at [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66186317/8593689), but this also has some problems:

- The first option relies on the `SystemDrive` environment variable, which for the reasons above is not guaranteed to hold the expected value on either Unix or Windows.
- All other options in this answer rely on [`os.TempDir`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#TempDir). On Windows, `os.TempDir` uses `GetTempPath`, returning the first non-empty value from `%TMP%`, `%TEMP%`, `%USERPROFILE%`, or the Windows directory. I do not believe I can trust that these environment variables have not been modified.

I also considered

```
func fsRootDir() string {
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        return "C:"
    }
    return "/"
}
```

but I thought I read somewhere that it is possible to change the filesystem root on Windows to something other than `C:`.

How can I get the root directory of a filesystem in such a way that it will work on both Windows and Unix?

Comment: Sometimes you must assume the user's environment is sane, and accept that they can always break things if they try hard enough (assuming you can even override `SystemDrive`, I'm not familiar with windows). You are also asking how to get the root of the filesystem, but `SystemDrive` may not be on the same filesystem as your working directory. What exactly do you consider to be "root" on windows?

Comment: (for the record, the windows [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats) shows that you start a path with a single slash just like unix to get the root of the current drive, which I think most would define as "the root of the filesystem", so I really see no problem with the proposed solution)

Comment: Windows has no concept of a singular "root of the filesystem"; all lettered drives are coequal from the FS perspective, and there is no FS which contains the drives. `SystemDrive` will get you the drive the OS is running from, but that's no more the "root" than any other drive. If that's good enough for your purposes, then just use `SystemDrive` on Windows using build flags or a switch on `runtime.GOOS`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not combine the two?

```
func fsRootDir() string {
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        return os.Getenv("SystemDrive")
    }
    return "/"
}
```

> A user could change the value of the SystemDrive environment variable on Windows to some bogus path.

No they can't, `SystemDrive` is a read-only variable.

Comment: I believe `SystemDrive` is not read-only. On my Windows 10 CMD, I can do "echo %SystemDrive%" and see `C:`, then "set SystemDrive=C:\", then "echo %SystemDrive", and then I see that the `SystemDrive` value was changed. I don't even need to be Administrator.